# How to create a jar file with folder contents only

Tags: batch-file, jar

I have a folder say xyz. I want to create a jar file with its contents only, not including the folder itself.

When I do

```
jar cvf xyz.jar xyz
```

I get the xyz.jar. When it is unzipped, I still have the xyz folder in there. I want to find file1, file2, file3 (which are the contents of xyz folder) when it is unzipped. How can I achieve this?